# Continuity of density of SDE

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider a stochastic differential equation in $\mathbb R^m$ with a parameter $\theta\in\mathbb R$:
\begin{equation}
    dX_t^{\theta,x} = v(\theta,X_t^{\theta,x})dt+\sigma(X_t^{\theta,x})\circ dW_t,~X_0^{\theta,x}=x.
\end{equation}
If we assume that the coefficients are smooth with bounded derivatives of all orders and the Hormander's condition holds at $x=x_0$ with $\theta=\theta_0$, then, for any $t>0$, $X_t^{\theta_0,x_0}$ has an smooth density.

Now if in addition, we know that there is a neighborhood $B$ of $x_0$ and a neighborhood $\Theta$ of $\theta_0$ such that the Hormander's condition holds for all $x\in B$ and all $\theta\in\Theta$, can we conclude that the density $p(t,\theta,x,y)$ of $X_t^{\theta,x}$ at point $y\in\mathbb R^m$ is continuous in $x\in B$, $y\in\mathbb R^m$, and $\theta\in \Theta$? If not, what additional assumptions do we need?